# Speed up comparison of Integer dates in Access front end to SQL Server back end

Tags: sql-server, performance, datetime, ms-access

I'm using Microsoft Access as a front end to a SQL Server data warehouse.  I need to speed up date comparisons in the front end.  The dates are stored as integers in the back end (e.g. today is 20191123).  In the Access front end I convert the integer dates to date data type:

```
CDate(Right([eventDate],2) & "-" & Mid([eventDate],5,2) & "-" & Left([eventDate],4))
```

That lets me do date comparisons.  For example, to find occurrences of eventDate between today and 1 month from today I put this in the WHERE clause:

```
Between Date() And DateAdd("m",1,Date())
```

I need a faster way of doing this.  My Access queries are reasonably fast without the date comparison in a WHERE clause, but as soon as I add the date comparison a query that previously ran in a fraction of a second takes 10-15 seconds.

Comment: There's an error in my Access CDate expression.  It should be `CDate(Mid([eventDate],5,2) & "-" & Right([eventDate],2) & "-" & Left([eventDate],4)`  Of course, this doesn't solve the speed problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize SQL Server SQL engine which is waaay faster than Access!

Create pass-through query in Access, then pass the parameters in "ODBC Connect Str" and copy/paste your Access SQL to this query.

If the connection string is right and if the SQL syntax is correct, it will be executed on the SQL Server side and it should be a lot faster. I mean a LOT.

Your Connection string should look like this:

ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=NameOfTheServer;DATABASE=NameOfTheDatabase;UID=Username;PWD=Password

Change the name of the driver if you are using a different one.

Note: you might want to change functions for date as those are not the same as in Access i.e. Date() in Access will be GETDATE() in SQL Server. CDate should be replaced with CAST or CONVERT, etc.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give that a try and report back.  In fact I'm already doing it on the SQL Server side and as you say it's much faster.

Comment: Thank you very much, Branislav.  I'm embarrassed to admit that I'd never tried a pass through query before--even though it's staring me in the face right there on the MS-Access query designer.  It took me under a minute to get it working: I just pasted in my existing DSN to build the ODBC connection string, pasted in the SQL from my existing SQL Server query, clicked Run and boom--the results appeared almost instantly as you said.  Now I need to revisit some of my other queries and restructure them as pass throughs.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert your Access dates to the *integer format* of the table field and then use:

```
Between Val(Format(Date(), "yyyymmdd")) And Val(Format(DateAdd("m",1,Date()), "yyyymmdd"))
```